# Redmine on Apache / Ubuntu

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, redmine

I cannot for the life of me get Redmine to run.  I'm not a Ruby programmer.  I tried using `apt-get`, but the installer was failing so I opted to do it by hand from Redmine's source.  When I try launching it in my browser, I get:

> **Application error**
>   Rails application failed to start properly

Here's the log file:

```
[notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 11163)
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.1$
[warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/project/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi" started (pid 11185)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- fcgi (LoadE$    
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'    
    from /project/redmine/public/dispatch.fcgi:4
```

First, here's my versions:

```
$ ruby -v; rails -v; gem -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
Rails 3.2.6
1.8.15

$ uname -a
Linux host 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

According to Redmine's documentation, that should work just fine.

I have redmine located at `/project/redmine`.  All files in that path have 755 permissions except the log folder, which is 666.  I'm using the following apache configuration:

```
Alias /redmine "/project/redmine/public/"
<Directory "/project/redmine/public/">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    RailsBaseURI /project/redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Apache is sporting the following modules:

> core mod_log_config mod_logio prefork http_core mod_so mod_actions **mod_alias** mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex **mod_cgi** mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env **mod_fastcgi** mod_mime mod_negotiation **mod_passenger** mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout **mod_rewrite** mod_setenvif mod_status

This is what my dispatch.fcgi.  It's the default, but the first two `require` lines were added by me trying to fix this.  It looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'fcgi'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed the `fcgi` gem? `sudo gem install fcgi`

Comment: I hadn't.  Installing it gets me past the hurdle I was facing.  Submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the part ``gem_original_require': no such file to load -- fcgi`of the error message, I assume you're missing the`fcgi` gem.

Install it with:

```
sudo gem install fcgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bitnami's Redmine stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) instead. It's an out-of-the-box package. After the installation Redmine is (and every other stack on Bitnami) ready to use. You just need to make the necessary project, tracker, user etc. definitions.